# How to reorder X axis date based on another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a text file here: https://login.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8c6b67865a6370b0af67
I need to re-arrange my 'X' axis based on the month column of the dataset. I have tried for a while and can't seem to find a way to achieve it. The graph below currently plots from Jan to Dec but I want the order to be from Oct to Sept. This is what I have so far:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   C_WY, WDAY, month, date [1]
  C_WY   WDAY month date       boxname           daily_mean
  <fct> <int> <fct> <date>     <chr>                  <dbl>
1 2001    274 Oct   2001-10-01 Confluence              22.3
2 2001    274 Oct   2001-10-01 DWSC-Yolo-CSlough       22.3
3 2001    274 Oct   2001-10-01 E_Delta                 21.8
4 2001    274 Oct   2001-10-01 Lower_SaC               22.3
5 2001    274 Oct   2001-10-01 Lower_SJR               22.5
6 2001    274 Oct   2001-10-01 Marsh                   23.0


ggplot(test2,aes(date,daily_mean,colour=boxname)) + 
                  geom_line(size=.8) +  
       scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month",date_labels = "%b",expand=c(0,0.5)) +
                  ggtitle("Test")
```

[image]

Comment: Can I ask why was my post deleted?

Comment: Your post is not deleted - I deleted my answer because it didn't answer your question. I didn't notice that full date in the x-axis. Could you post just enough sample data to illustrate the problem, and please do it in a copy/pasteable way? That makes it easier than downloading and importing your file and doing type conversions, and keeps it future proof as a resource even if your file link disappears. Something like `dput(test2[sample(1:nrow(test2), size = 40), ])` to share 40 rows of data would be great.

Comment: My dataset has around 4,000 records. The only way to show all the months is to try the entire dataset, otherwise, 50 records will only show the first month. That's why I provided a link instead.

Comment: The code I shared will do a random sample of records. In the extremely unlikely event they are all in the first month, run it again for a different random sample.

Comment: Minimal examples are always easier to work with and understand than examples with thousands of rows, and copy/pasteable examples always get faster attention than links because it makes it so much nicer for the people trying to help.

Comment: Note that if you want the date 2001-10-01 to appear before the date 2001-09-01, your easiest bet will probably be to modify they year of the Oct-Dec data to change it to 2000...

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate) 

test2 %>% 
   mutate(date = case_when(month %in% c("Oct", "Nov", "Dec") ~ date - years(1),
                     TRUE ~ date)) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(date, daily_mean, colour=boxname)) + 
     geom_line(size=.8) +  
     scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month",
                  date_labels = "%b",expand=c(0,0.5)) +
     ggtitle("Test")
```

Comment: @B Williams --- Did that work for you? when I run it it throws this error : Error: Column `date` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable

Comment: @Salvador - you could use `test2 %>% ungroup() %>% ...`

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE:*** I ended up going way back into my dataset and in the code and found that I had lost my next year data. ggplot was looking at only one year of data instead of going beyond December. Thanks for trying.